# ElasticSearch: Ids ending in period/dot

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are experiencing quite an interesting situation these days. We had ElasticSearch 6.2 previously and upgraded it to 7.1. It looks like some data that was saved with the old version is not compatible anymore with the new and I am looking for a solution.

This is an example of a record saved with the old version:

````
        "_index" : "products-0_v7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "18442_Product one.",
        "_score" : 11.565834,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "",
          "priceExVat" : 15.65
        }```
````

The problem is that this value can no longer be retrieved by the Nest library:

```
_client.Get<Product>(productId, x => x.Index(index))
```

When debugging the call, the period sign is stripped. The same thing happen during an Index operation:

```
var indexRequest = new IndexRequest<InvoicableProduct>(product, aliasErpimport, new Id(product.Id));
          
var ret = _client.Index(indexRequest);
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Is it possible to have the period not stripped at all? It works if you index a value such as "Product one. " (with an extra space) but that will create a duplicate since the original record has no trailing space.

Comment: According to the [upgrade guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) you should upgrade 6.2 to 6.8 first, then to 7.x. If that doesn't resolve the issue it might be `nest` bug; Elasticsearch 7.x indexes and retrieves docs with ID ending with a dot with no issues.

Comment: @ilvar it is working if I'm doing it from kibana with curl commands but not from the Nest library. The library is stripping the dot when making the call

Comment: Consider filing an issue for [nest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of investigating the problem I came to a solution. After creating a new project from scratch and running the same code it worked so I had to figure out what was breaking it in the current code.

Web.config had a line of code similar to this one:

`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />`

The problem, turns out, is that httpRuntime is lacking the targetFramework property.

This fixed it:

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="2147483647" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />`